# Parsing complex logs with boost spirit

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

I am having problems while parsing a complex log with boost::spirit. I am not able of getting the data as I want, mostly because blanks skippers mess everything up.

I have the next text file called log.txt:

```
1:[2017-Feb-18 01:57:55.341100] <INFO, SIMULATING> => CPU | Name: CAR (ID: 0) - ID: 1
2:[2017-Feb-18 01:57:55.344100] <INFO, SENDING_DATA> => IO | Io_out - ABS: 1
3:[2017-Feb-18 01:57:55.344100] <INFO, SIMULATING> => CPU | Status: Ok
4:[2017-Feb-18 01:57:55.346100] <INFO, SIMULATING> => MSS | Random Number: 0x4D080020
5:[2017-Feb-18 01:57:55.346100] <INFO, SIMULATING> => CPU | Entering mode: AUTO
6:[2017-Feb-18 01:57:59.583342] <INFO, SENDING_DATA> => IO | Io_in - BRK: 1
7:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:24.604773] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => DET | Point: 004811
8:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:24.844787] <INFO, SENDING_DATA> => PC | Send msg 1: 0101000000000000
9:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:26.204865] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => PC2 | Receive msg 8: 0801000000000000
10:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:28.706008] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => PC1 | Receive msg 2: 0201000000000000
11:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:29.345045] <INFO, SENDING_DATA> => PC | Send msg 3: 0301000000000000
12:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:29.706065] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => PC1 | Receive msg 4: 04010000F8B8C1A7
13:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:29.846073] <INFO, SENDING_DATA> => PC | Send msg 5: 05010000F8B8C1A7
14:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:32.206208] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => PC1 | Receive msg 6: 06010001F8B8C1A8
15:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:32.366217] <INFO, SENDING_DATA> => PC | Send msg 7: 07010001F8B8C1A8
17:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:32.406220] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => PC2 | Receive msg 6: 06010001F8B8C1A8
18:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:32.875246] <INFO, SENDING_DATA> => PC | Send msg 7: 07010001F8B8C1A9
19:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:32.906248] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => PC1 | Receive msg 6: 06010001F8B8C1A9
20:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:33.386276] <INFO, SENDING_DATA> => PC | Send msg 7: 07010001F8B8C1AA
```

And i am using the next code for parsing it into a boost fusion adapted struct:

```
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>


struct Message
{
    std::string line;
    std::string date;
    std::string time;
    char id;
    std::string hex;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Message,
    (std::string, Message::line)
    (std::string, Message::date)
    (std::string, Message::time)
    (char, Message::id)
    (std::string, Message::hex)
)

std::vector<Message> messages;

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace repo = boost::spirit::repository;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

void main()
{
    std::ifstream in("C:/log.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    in >> std::noskipws;//No white space skipping

    if (!in)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not open input file: " << std::endl;
        return;
    }//if

    boost::spirit::istream_iterator first(in);
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator last;

    bool result = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, 
        *repo::seek[qi::eol
            >> +ascii::char_("0-9") 
            >> ":["
            >> +ascii::char_("0-9a-fA-F-")
            >> +ascii::char_("0-9.:")
            >> "] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => PC"
            >> ascii::char_('1', '2')
            >> "| Receive msg 6:"
            >> +ascii::char_("0-9a-fA-F")
            >> qi::eol],
        ascii::blank,
        messages);

    return;
}
```

When executing code, the data is bad formatted within the struct. May someone tries to help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you tried to use`qi::lexeme`? Seems that the ids are appended in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I added a `lexeme` i was able to parse the following one line log file:

```
14:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:32.206208] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => PC1 | Receive msg 6: 06010001F8B8C1A8
```

This is my code. It still failed to read the original `log.txt`. But I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve.

```
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>

struct Message
{
    std::string line;
    std::string date;
    std::string time;
    char id;
    std::string hex;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Message,
    (std::string, Message::line)
    (std::string, Message::date)
    (std::string, Message::time)
    (char, Message::id)
    (std::string, Message::hex)
)

std::vector<Message> messages;

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace repo = boost::spirit::repository;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace ph=boost::phoenix;

void main()
{
    std::ifstream in("C:/temp/log2.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    in >> std::noskipws;//No white space skipping

    if (!in)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not open input file: " << std::endl;
        return;
    }//if
    Message msg;
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator first(in);
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator last;
    bool result = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,
//      *repo::seek[
        (+ascii::char_("0-9")
        >> qi::lexeme[":[" >> +ascii::char_("0-9a-fA-F-")]
        >> +ascii::char_("0-9.:")
        >> "] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => PC"
        >> ascii::char_('1', '2')
        >> "| Receive msg 6:"
        >> +ascii::char_("0-9a-fA-F") )
        % qi::eol,
/*      >> qi::eol],*/
        ascii::blank,
        messages);
        for (auto msg : messages) {
            std::cout << msg.line << ", " << msg.date << ", " << msg.time << ", " << msg.id << ", " << msg.hex << std::endl;
        }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Nice and acurate answer, but still not working as needed. I need to parse the whole log file for retrieving all the information contained in msg6: I need the line number, the date, the time, the cpu id and the hex message. In order of find all the msg6 lines, the *repo::seek directive is needed, as well as the first qi::eol and the last >> qi::eol. Doing so, I get the right info into the messages list for line 17 and 19 of the log, but the fist parsed message in line 14 contains bad formatted data, because all the previous fields have been appended. Any further ideo for fixing this up?up

Comment: Ah. I see. Is there some documentation for `repo::seek`? It is completely new to me. Hence I remove it. It seems that for the id the strings for the lines 2,3,4,5,...14 are concatenated. Resulting in this obscure 234567...14 id string.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/seek.html

Comment: It seems that forcing the attribute of the "interesting" line to be `Message` (by using an extra rule) solves the problem of the different strings being combined into one. [Example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yIjkiSzy5Wseo11n).

Comment: Seems that Ilonesmiz solved the problem. But I have no idea why. :-)

Comment: I am sorry, but still not working as expected. In your lite version of the log the first non msg6 line lacks from a beginning eol, so the next line is a msg 6 and it is parsed rightly. But if you add "12:[2017-Feb-18 01:58:29.706065] <INFO, RECEIVING_DATA> => PC1 | Receive msg 4: 04010000F8B8C1A7" at the beginning of your std::string, programs keeps working in a wrong way as before.

Comment: @Pablo Yes, I see the problem now. I think [`qi::hold`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/hold.html) can help with that (and the extra rule does not seem to be needed).